# Set Null Value as Default for Missing Table Fields

Tags: java, sql, google-bigquery

I'm using Java and SQL to move data to a new table. I want to:

1. Pull data from an old table in BigQuery
2. Update/modify several entries
3. Push it to a different existing table in BigQuery

Unfortunately, some of the old data follows a different schema. Some old tables might have anywhere from one to a couple of hundred missing columns (fields). There isn't any reliable way for me to generate or fill in this missing data, so I've settled with leaving it null. How can I add a column with a default null value?

At the moment, I'm using a SQL QueryJobConfiguration to pull, update, and push data back to BQ:

```
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = 
           QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
              "SELECT  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d %T %Y', CONCAT(time, ' 2018')) MyTimestamp, * EXCEPT(time)"
               + "FROM `myProject:MyDataset.MyTable` ")
              .setUseLegacySql(false)
              .setWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)    
              .setDestinationTable(TableId.of(MyOtherDataset, MyOtherTable))
              .build();
```

When I attempt to run this, BigQuery throws an exception claiming the data is missing a column:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Invalid schema update. Field OtherField is missing in new schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of testing, I found out that BQ wasn't letting me push because I had several fields set to "REQUIRED" instead of "NULLABLE". I had completely forgotten about them. Fortunately, BigQuery has an experimental method: setSchemaUpdateOptions. You can implement it like so:

```
List<SchemaUpdateOption> SchemaUpdate = Arrays.asList(JobInfo.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION);
.setSchemaUpdateOptions(SchemaUpdate)
```

ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION essentially lets you temporarily replace REQUIRED mode on any fields with NULLABLE.